# dynatrace monitor war deployment

Tags: dynatrace

I am trying to use dynatrace to monitor the deployment of a war in tomcat.

The deployment of this spring application takes more than 10 min and I would like to know the bottlenecks in the initialization of the application context.

I started tomcat with no applications deployed and then connected from the dynatrace client. I was able to view certain tomcat lifecycle events in the pure paths

Then I started  the hot deployment of the war. But dynatrace does not show the deployment process. Should we enable any particular method in tomcat to monitor the  deployment process ?

Comment: What version of Dynatrace are you using?

Comment: Dynatrace version 6.3

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Dynatrace AppMon only instruments certain execution pathes fully with PurePaths, mostly things that happen during production use, e.g. servlet calls, database queries, well-known frameworks, ...

You can add custom instrumentation in the Dynatrace Client in the System Profile settings in the section "Sensors". The easiest way is "Browse..." where you get a tree of all classes that are found in your application and where you can then choose which ones should be instrumented additionally.

For this you will need to find out which method is executed in Tomcat to execute the deployment. After you add this method, it will show up as PurePath in the PurePath Dashlet.

See https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/sensors/ for full documentation on this topic.

Another possibility would be to use the "CPU Runtime" Dashlet to record CPU usage while the deployment is executed. There you would see the overall top CPU consumers in all of Tomcat, which might show the deployment actions and where the time is actually spent.

See https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/appmon-client/dashlets/cpu-sampling-dashlet/ for an in-depth description of this functionality.